# Count files and then copy files if there are files missing

Tags: file, batch-file, count, copy

I need to setup a batch that looks at a folder to see if it has all the files it needs.  If it doesn't find the number of files, then it copies them.

So my pseudo code would be something like this.

```
If c:\folder filecount NOT 1000 files then copy \\\server\source\\*.* c:\folder
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

This should do it

```
@echo off
setlocal

for /f "tokens=1" %%a in ('dir c:\path ^|find "File(s)"') do (
    if %%a NEQ 1000 xcopy "\\server\source\*.*" "c:\folder"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for /f %%a in ('dir /a-d /b ^|find /c /v ""') do if not "%%~a"=="1000" xcopy "\\server\source\*.*" "c:\folder"
```